# Bug that fills entire pixel grid with color

Tags: javascript

I created a pixel grid with vanilla JS and added both erase and draw modes. The only point of the draw mode is to return to the default functionality (fills cell(s) with color upon clicking a cell or pressing mouse pointer button while dragging across multiple cells) after using the erase mode.

If you try drawing quickly after selecting draw mode then do mouseup/release the mouse pointer, the entire grid is filled in, and if you try clicking 'submit' to clear the grid, it doesn't work.

I experienced the grid-filling problem before and fixed it with an if statement

```
if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
```

which worked in the default function controlling drawing (i.e., that works before you select erase or draw mode), and included it in the function for draw mode, but it isn't preventing the grid from being filled in, and I'm not sure why clicking 'submit' doesn't clear the grid once the bug occurs.

To view my full code, view my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/MQRxJZ).

Here's my function for draw mode that seems to be the source of these issues:

```
// Allows user to return to (default) draw mode after using 'erase' button. Note 'down' was set to false in variable above
drawMode.addEventListener('click', function() {
  pixelCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    down = true;
    pixelCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        down = false;
    });
    // Ensures cells won't be colored if grid is left while pointer is held down
    pixelCanvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
      down = false;
    });
    pixelCanvas.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
      const color = document.querySelector('.color-picker').value;
      // While mouse pointer is pressed and within grid boundaries, fills cell with selected color. Inner if statement fixes bug that fills in entire grid
        if (down) {
        if (e.target.tagName === 'TD') {
            e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
      }
    });
  });
  // Enables single-cell coloring while in draw mode
  pixelCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const color = document.querySelector('.color-picker').value;
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Inspect the HTML when the bug happens, you'll see that the *table*'s background-color is being set, which is why it's not eraseable. Try using this instead, to ensure that the element about to be colored is a pixel (`td`) and not anything else:

```
pixelCanvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'td') return;
  const color = document.querySelector('.color-picker').value;
  // ...
```